# How to set Google font icons in Vuetify expansion panel

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have some difficulty setting a Google icon inside an expansion panel. Usually, you can just set them via the collapse-icon or expand-icon props inside either the `<v-expansion-panel>` component or the `<v-expansion-panel-title-component>` according to the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-expansion-panel-title/).

However, an icon has to be inserted like this:

```
<span class="material-symbols-outlined"> arrow_drop_down </span>
```

And I have no idea how to get this to work with 2 different icons. What you cannot do is simply say:

```
<v-expansion-panel-title
expandIcon="arrow_drop_down"
collapseIcon="arrow_drop_up"
>
```

Also, I tried using the actions slot but I am unsure of how to set the icons here

```
  <v-expansion-panel-title>
    <template v-slot:actions>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> arrow_drop_down </span>
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> arrow_drop_up </span>
    </template>
```

This will give me 2 icons next to each other. Maybe someone can show me the proper use of the slot and how to set the icons there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slots in Vuetify expose certain values about it's state as you can see in described in the documentation:

```
actions
{
  collapseIcon:
    | string
    | (string | [string, number])[]
    | (new () => any)
    | FunctionalComponent
  disabled: boolean
  expanded: boolean
  expandIcon:
    | string
    | (string | [string, number])[]
    | (new () => any)
    | FunctionalComponent
  readonly: boolean
}
```

You can use the "expanded" boolean state to dynamically adjust the rendering, write a v-if v-else statement to conditionally render different items according to its state.

```
<template #actions="{expanded}">
  <span v-if="expanded" class="material-symbols-outlined"> arrow_drop_down </span>
  <span v-else class="material-symbols-outlined"> arrow_drop_up </span>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi Alexander. Thanks for answering :-) You said the slots *expose* values, so that means we can extract the panel components state and I see why you chose the solution using the "expanded" property. I was expecting someone'd use "expandIcon" or "collapseIcon". I wonder what this would be used for then.. Anyways, thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: Hi angularNoob if you want pass a string as an icon you have to install the icon font you would like to use. It's explain here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/
Let's say you install the mdi icon font then you can could do expandIcon="mdi-arrow-down"